# Put hashtags in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

my problem is quite simple, I would like to put hashtags in a text from a list of them.
I have tried every way but I can't find the solution.
Thanks in advance.

```js
let arr = ['aa', 'bb']

let caption = `Hello | World `;

arr.forEach(el => {
  console.log(`#${el}`)
  caption.concat(' ', `#${el}`)
});

console.log(caption) // I want : "Hello | World #aa #bb" ; But it puts me "Hello | World"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) does not modify the original string. You have to assign the returned value of `concat` back to `caption`.

```js
let arr = ['aa', 'bb']

let caption = `Hello | World `;

arr.forEach(el => {
  console.log(`#${el}`)
  caption = caption.concat(' ', `#${el}`)
});

console.log(caption) // prints : "Hello | World #aa #bb"
```